# Git equivalent for TFS (TFVC) Compare with Workspace Version in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

When there are incoming commits (fetch), how do I manually review and manually merge each and every change using a diff GUI **from** "Incoming Commit" **to** LOCAL code in order to understand exactly how the branch is changing and to resolve both merge conflicts and logical conflicts BEFORE attempting to pull (fetch + merge) or merge?

A TFS (TFVC) equivalent is **"Compare with Workspace Version"** After drilling down into history and change sets.

[image: compare with Workspace Version]

With git in VS I only get compare with previous and I need to compare to local at the very least, if not whatever I want.

[image]

Notes: I'm using Git as implemented in Visual Studio 2015 (Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2). I welcome answers that connect or map the concepts terminology and coder practices between TFS and Git instead of just, git doesn't work that way ect.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

TFS has two version control systems by default. They are Git and TFVC.

> Git is a distributed version control system. Each developer has a copy
>   of the source repository on their dev machine. Developers can commit
>   each set of changes on their dev machine and perform version control
>   operations such as history and compare without a network connection.
>   Branches are lightweight.
>
> Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) is a centralized version
>   control system. Typically, team members have only one version of each
>   file on their dev machines. Historical data is maintained only on the
>   server. Branches are path-based and created on the server.

As Git is designed for many different branches and getting them back into main repo, you can only compare between commits or branches.

For your scenario, you need to go to TFS web access, and compare between branches to see which commits exist on which branches.

[image]

Comment: Good information! However, I'm looking to compare [remote branch commit] (git-vs labels them as 'incoming commits') to [local branch commit] (not pushed yet). This answer compares two branches already pushed. Is my request simply not possible? Or is it covered by some series of git steps that I simply haven't learned yet? So far git seems like a mosh pit of branches and commits and I'm trying to learn how to traverse two code states in order to maneuver and cleanly contribute to my branch. Thx.

Comment: @TheDev6, I got your point, but there is no such feature by default in VS/TFS IDE. :-(. I have submitted a UserVoice for your request at website below, you can vote it: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/16646929-add-feature-of-compare-remote-branch-commit-with-l

Comment: Thanks for adding the feature request! I'll go vote for it. And maybe there is a different work flow that I need to adopt like forking or more short running branches that allows me to accomplish the goal.